# django-mptt вывод субкатегорий при клике на node категорию

Tags: python, django

При клике на {{ node.name }} Django выводит все подкатегории всех категорий. Не понимаю что мне нужно передавать во views.py и указывать в шаблоне, чтобы при клике на {{ node.name }} я получал только конкретные субкатегории выбранной категории.  Субкатегории выводятся на этой же странице (services__search__categories-list__submenu имеет display: one) и отображается через js (slideToggle())

Html:

```html
<div class="services__categories-list">
  <ul> 
    {% recursetree categories %} 
    <li>
      <h3>
        <a class="services__categories-list__item" href="">{{ node.name }}</a>
      </h3>
    </li> 
    {% endrecursetree %} 
  </ul>
  <div class="services__search__categories-list__submenu">
    <ul> 
      {% for category in branch_categories %} 
      <li>
        <h4>
          <a href="">{{ category.name }}</a>
        </h4>
      </li> 
      {% endfor %} 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Service, Doctor, Document, Category

def main(request):
    """Вывод главной страницы"""
    services = Service.objects.all()
    doctors = Doctor.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    branch_categories = categories.get_descendants(include_self=False)
    return render(request, "main/main.html", {"services": services, "doctors": doctors, "categories": categories, "branch_categories": branch_categories})
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):
    """Описание категории услуг"""
    name = models.CharField("Категория", max_length=255)
    #url = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        'self', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
        db_index=True,
        related_name="children",
        verbose_name="Главная категория"
    )

    class MPTTMeta:
        """Сортировка по вложенности"""
        order_insertion_by = ("name",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Категория"
        verbose_name_plural = "Категории"
        db_table = "app_categories"


class Service(models.Model):
    """Описание услуги"""
    name = models.CharField("Услуга", max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    preparation = models.TextField("Подготовка")
    price = models.CharField("Цена", max_length=8)
    category = TreeForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="категория", related_name="category")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Услуга"
        verbose_name_plural = "Услуги"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

смог решить данный вопрос встроенным в django-mttp методом get_children.

```
<div class="services__categories-list">
  <ul> 
    {% for category in categories %} 
    <li class="services__categories-item">
      <h3 class="services__categories-list__item">&#10059; {{ category.name }}</h3>
      <div class="submenu">
        <ul> {% for cat in category.get_children %} <li>
            <h4>
              <a href="">{{ cat.name }}</a>
            </h4>
          </li> 
          {% endfor %} 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li> 
    {% endfor %} 
    </ul>
</div>
```